# tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() leaves an empty file on local directory

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am using `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` and using SMTP to send emails, however, I found every single time after running the batch, it will generate an empty file under batch location (not temp).

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp:
    file_name = f"Risk_Report_{context}: {','.join(book)}_{risk_date}_{','.join(risk_measure)}.csv"
    subject = f"Success:Risk_Report_{context}:{','.join(book)}_{risk_date}_{','.join(risk_measure)}"
    email_body = ''
    attach_path = os.path.join(temp, file_name)
    df = pd.DataFrame(Risk.result_flatten(result_enrich))
    df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
    table_html = df.to_html()
    email_body += f"{table_html}"
```

This is the last line of the batch.

I found after finishing this block during my debugging (say I add some a=3 before the batch finishes and step into), the weird file will not emerge. It only emerges after the batch finishes.

The file is exactly with the file_name.

Is there anybody meeting the same issue here and got some solution? Many thanks.

Update:

1. I tried no temporary directory, and the file still exists:

   ```
            file_name = f"Risk_Report_{context}: {','.join(book)}_{risk_date}_{','.join(risk_measure)}.csv"
            subject = f"Success:Risk_Report_{context}:{','.join(book)}_{risk_date}_{','.join(risk_measure)}"
            email_body = ''
            attach_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0], file_name)
            df=pd.DataFrame()
            # df = pd.DataFrame(Risk.flatten_all_dict(result_enrich))
            # table_html = df.to_html()
            # email_body += f"{table_html}"
            df.to_csv(attach_path, index=False)
            os.remove(attach_path)
   ```

There is still the empty file.

2. I found the bug and update file_name to attach_path, the file will not show. However, I've met problem when using :
   messaging.send_email(subject=subject, body=email_body, attachments=attach_path, to=receiver)
   after wards, the attaching method is :

   ```
            with open(os.path.basename(path), 'rb') as f:
                part = MIMEApplication(f.read())
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(path))
                msg.attach(part)
   ```

And it said no file for the path.

Any idea why?

Comment: Should `df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)` use `attach_path` instead of `file_name`?

Comment: Windows? Then files still open might not be removed.

Comment: In update 2, why are you calling `os.path.basename`?

Comment: @user2357112 my bad, just fix the issue if I use temporarydirectory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)` you're writing the dataframe as CSV into `file_name`, implicitly in the current directory.

You should probably use `attach_path`, the concatenation of the temporary directory and the filename.

Or maybe write the data to a *temporary file*, and use `file_name` only as an explicit attachment name (overriding the filename), assuming that is its purpose and whatever API you use for mail composition allows this.

As `to_csv` can write to a file-like object, depending on the amount of data and again on the mail API you might also be able to work entirely in-memory, or at least use a spooled temporary file (such that you don't need to write small files to disk).